# bash, ps -o pcpu,args divided by another char

Tags: bash, ps

Is possible divide output from `ps -o pcpu,args` with another char? And round `pcpu` to integer?

INPUT

```
ps -axo pcpu,args --no-headers | sort -t. -nk1,2 -k4,4 -r | head -n 1
```

OUTPUT

```
 5.1 php-fpm: pool www
```

NEED

```
 5;php-fpm: pool www
```

Comment: If you want a one-liner,  this may be difficult. But, let us first simplify your command: Is `ps  -axo pcpu,args --no-headers --sort=cpu | tail -1` the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simplified your command by incorporating the "sort" operation into `ps`. To split the output into two parts (`$a` and `$b`), I used the `read` built-in. To print these two variables, I used the `printf` built-in:

```
read a b <<<"$(ps -axo pcpu,args --no-headers --sort=pcpu | tail -1 )"
printf "%.f;%s\n" "$a" "$b"
```